# tvOS button transitions & view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, video, tvos

I'm working on an app for tvOS — I have 2 questions. I have a video, and once the video ends I want a button to transition onto the screen (fade in) to get to the next screen.

1. If I have say, 10 videos or more, should each video have its own "view controller"?
2. I've been searching the tvOS developer library for button transitions, I came across the `UIViewControllerIneteractiveTransitioning` but this seems to be more for the view transition itself.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: how did you eventually solve the 10 videos "should each have its own controller" problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same view controller and keep on playing the video on button click by changing the video path/URL

Check below URL for animation if you are looking for transition though they are not tested on tvOS:

https://github.com/quantumarun/BottomUp-Animation

https://github.com/quantumarun/AwesomeAnimationsiOS

Comment: Thanks a mill Arun, much appreciated!

Comment: Let me know if you are looking for specific animation... I am in process of creating suite of animation and can add your suggestion..

Comment: Originally I wanted the the button to zoom into the centre of the screen, once the video ended that or 'fade in', the button will then lead to the next video.  Thanks Arun! :)